# Hibernate. Can't delete by specific column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have an HQL query

```
private static final String USER_ID_PARAM = "u_id";

private static final String DELETE_BY_USER_ID = 
        "delete from Data where user_id=:" + USER_ID_PARAM;
```

Delete method

```
    @Override
    public void deleteUserData(long userId) {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        try {
            Query q = s.createQuery(DELETE_BY_USER_ID);
            q.setParameter(USER_ID_PARAM, userId);
            q.executeUpdate();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             if (s != null && s.isOpen()) {
                 s.close();
             }
         }
    }
```

But it isn't work. It's seems like executeUpdate() executing forever.

Interesting that the SELECT query works well

```
private static final String SELECT_BY_USER_ID = 
            "from Data where user_id=:" + USER_ID_PARAM;

    @Override
    public List<Data> userData(long userId) {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        try {
            Query q = s.createQuery(SELECT_BY_USER_ID);
            q.setParameter(USER_ID_PARAM, userId);
            q.setCacheable(true);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Data> userData = (List<Data>) q.list();
            return userData;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return null;
         } finally {
             if (s != null && s.isOpen()) {
                 s.close();
             }
         }
    }
```

Create "data" table query

> CREATE TABLE data ( id SERIAL, url VARCHAR(128), login VARCHAR(64),
>   password VARCHAR(128), email VARCHAR(128), extra VARCHAR(256), user_id
>   BIGINT UNSIGNED, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES
>   users (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);

### SOLVED.

I used Transaction and it's works. **Thank wero**.

```
    @Override
    public boolean deleteUserData(long userId) {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tran = s.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Query q = s.createQuery(DELETE_BY_USER_ID);
            q.setParameter(USER_ID_PARAM, userId);
            int updated = q.executeUpdate();
            tran.commit();
            return updated > 0;

         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

             if (tran != null) {
                 tran.rollback();
             }
             return false;
         }
    }
```

Comment: do you have some error?

Comment: It's seems like executeUpdate() executing forever.

Comment: try to wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: It's works! Thank you.